# Python: How do I add a “Final Grade” converter in my Grading System Calculator

Tags: python

I kind of have an idea what to do, but I can't figure it out. The program needs to be able to get the students name and three test scores, then get the average score (percentage) out of the three scores. After that, you need to convert the score (percentage) into a grade.

**EDIT:**
How would I remove the space in the middle of the grade and the "%"?

- Please press "Enter" to begin
- Enter your Name: Jordan Simpson
- First test score: 67%
- Second test score: 78%
- Third test score: 89%
- Final letter grade: C+
- Jordan Simpson test score is: **78.0 %**
- Do you want to restart the program?

---

**Grading Scale:**

[image: Grading Scale]

---

```
input ('Please press "Enter" to begin')

while True:
    import math

    studentName = str(input('Enter your Name: '))
    firstScore = int(float(input('First test score: ').replace('%', '')))
    secondScore = int(float(input('Second test score: ').replace('%', '')))
    thirdScore = int(float(input('Third test score: ').replace('%', '')))
    scoreAvg = (firstScore + secondScore + thirdScore) / 3

    def grade():
        if scoreAvg >= 93 and <= 100:
            return 'A'
        if scoreAvg <= 92.9 and >= 89:
            return 'A-'
        if scoreAvg <= 88.9 and >= 87:
            return 'B+'
        if scoreAvg <= 86.9 and >= 83:
            return 'B'
        if scoreAvg <= 82.9 and >= 79:
            return 'B-'
        if scoreAvg <= 78.9 and >= 77:
            return 'C+'
        if scoreAvg <= 76.9 and >= 73:
            return 'C'
        if scoreAvg <= 72.9 and >= 69:
            return 'C-'
        if scoreAvg <= 68.9 and >= 67:
            return 'D+'
        if scoreAvg <= 66.9 and >= 60:
            return 'D'
        return 'F'

    print(grade(scoreAvg))
    print(studentName, "test score is: ",scoreAvg,'%')


    endProgram = input ('Do you want to restart the program?')

    if endProgram in ('no', 'No', 'NO', 'false', 'False', 'FALSE'):
        break
```

Comment: your current program would seem to do the job ? just add scoreAvg as a parameter and capture the return value. Although i guess someone more of a python expert could give a more succinct way of doing this.

Comment: No need to check the scores multiple times in the grade() method. Try `if scoreAvg > 93: return 'A' if scoreAvg > 89: return 'A-'` etc.

Comment: @Moop
line 35, in <module>
    print(grade[scoreAvg])
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

Comment: you can also use a dictionary with Grades and values :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really sure what your question is, but here is a more succinct way of getting the letter grade.

```
>>> scores = [93, 89, 87, 83, 79, 77, 73, 69, 67, 60, 0]
>>> grades = ['A', 'A-', 'B+', 'B', 'B-', 'C+', 'C', 'C-', 'D+', 'D', 'F']
>>> 
>>> def gradeFor(s):
...     grade_scores = zip(scores, grades)
...     for score, grade in grade_scores:
...        if s >= score:
...            return grade

>>> gradeFor(87)
B+
>>> gradeFor(89)
A-
>>> gradeFor(88)
B+
>>> gradeFor(67)
D+
>>> gradeFor(72)
C-
>>> gradeFor(40)
F
```

Also, you can do

```
if endProgram.lower() in ('no', 'false'):
```

Comment: line 24, in <module>
    print(gradeFor[scoreAvg])
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Or a generator: `def gradeFor(s):
 return next(grade for score, grade in grade_scores if s >= score)`

Comment: I fixed that in your code.  You need to call `gradeFor[scoreAvg]` like `gradeFor(scoreAvg)`... not the `()` instead of `[]`.

Comment: @JordanSimps It's a function, not an array - use rounded brackets. `gradeFor(scoreAvg)`

Comment: What does "x" stand for in the return? Could you please explain how the "def gradeFor(score)" is figured out, please?

Comment: you're making it harder to read than it needs to be: `gradeFor(s): for grade, score in zip(grades, scores): if s >= score: return grade`

Comment: @rmmh Could you give me some sort of Instant Messenger I could ask a question, personally, through?